# How to efficiently populate a numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

I want to create a 2D numpy array of size (`N_r` * `N_z`).

Across columns, the elements for 1 specific column (say `j`) shall be created based on the value `r_thresh[j]`.
So 1 column (say `j`) out of the total of `N_z` columns in the numpy 2D array is created as:

```
(np.arange(N_r) + 0.5) * r_thresh[j] # this gives an array of size (1, N_r)
```

Of course, the column `j + 1` shall be created as:

```
(np.arange(N_r) + 0.5) * r_thresh[j+1] # this gives an array of size (1, N_r)
```

`r_thresh` is a numpy array of size `(1, N_z)`, already populated with values before I want to create the 2D array.

I want to ask you how do I go further and use this ''rule'' of creating each element of the numpy 2D array and actually create the whole array, in the most efficient way possible (speed-wise).

I initially wrote all the code using 2 nested for loops and plain python lists and the code worked, but took forever to run.

More experienced programmers told me to avoid for loops and use numpy because it's the best.

I now understand how to create 1D arrays using numpy `np.arange()` instruction, but I lack the knowledge on how to extrapolate this to 2 Dimensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `einsum`. In the case of `r_thresh` with the shape of `(N_z,)`, you can use this code:

```
res = np.einsum("i,j->ij", np.arange(N_r) + 0.5, r_thresh)
```

Also, you can reshape `np.arange(N_r) + 0.5` to the shape `(N_r,1)` and `r_thresh` to the shape `(1,N_z)`. Thus, you can use the dot product (for Python version > 3.5):

```
res = (np.arange(N_r) + 0.5).reshape(N_r,1) @ r_thresh.reshape(1,N_z)
```

or following to the comment of [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj):

```
res = (np.arange(N_r) + 0.5)[:,None] @ r_thresh[None,:]
```

**EDIT1**

The comment of [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) is also very helpful (I pasted this into my answer to see better):

```
res = (np.arange(N_r) + 0.5)[:,None] * r_thresh
res = np.outer(np.arange(N_r) + 0.5, r_thresh)
```

**IN ADDITION**

You can also use `tensordot`:

```
res = np.tensordot((np.arange(N_r) + 0.5)[:,None], r_thresh[:,None], axes=[[-1],[-1]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never known about this einstein summation instruction. Fortunately I have a master of physics degree , so time to explore the documentation of this instruction! Much appreciated! Dot product seems easier.

Comment: `(np.arange(N_r) + 0.5)[:,None] * r_thresh` uses broadcasting and 'ordinary' multiplication.  `np.outer` also works.